# Whats the best way to get all objects from a S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

To get all objects out of my S3 Bucket programmatically I currently use the `ListObjectsV2Request` first. Then I iterate over all received keys and get the individual objects for each key with a `GetObjectRequest`.

I am experiencing performance problems which lead to my objects not being displayed fast enough in the frontend.

Is there any other better way to get all objects from an S3 Bucket, maybe with only one request?

Comment: Unforunately no, worse, if you have many objects you need to paginate.

Comment: Please add some details here: 1. What should be the output of your program (something that you send to frontend)? 2. What do you call performance problem - memory is high or just slow processing or whatever?

Comment: @scholl123 Please edit your question to add more details. What do you mean by "get all objects" -- do you mean download, or are you just wanting to "list" them in a front-end? How many objects are in the bucket? (Please edit your question with these details, rather than answering in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `TransferManager`, maybe it will solve your issue. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html#tranfermanager-download-directory

Comment: But that would mean that I would have to put the files somewhere, right? I just want to process the content in my program, similar to the S3AsyncClient.GetObject where i can use an AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes

Answer (score 0):

If your task is to copy all files from one bucket to another, I would suggest you trying https://rclone.org/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my task is to read all the objects from a S3 bucket and use the data in my frontend, so no i don't want to store the files somewhere else, i just want to use the data.